# Checkbox checked per row only using JQuery in blade template

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, checkbox

Is it possible to check only the checkbox which belongs to a row in a table inside blade template using jQuery? I have this table view

[image]

I want to check only the students belonging to 7-A without including the students in 7-B. How do I make it work?
I'm using a `for-each` loop to display the data in my table. With my current jQuery code, it will check all the item inside the table.

**View Table:**

```
<table class="table  table-hover table-bordered" > 
  <tr>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Student</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach($sections as $section)
  <tr>
    <td>  
      <input type="checkbox" id="chckHead" />
      <label>{{$section->section_code}}<label>
    </td>
    <td>  
      @foreach($section->lead as $bt)
      <input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" name="lead_id[]" value="{{$bt->id}}">
      <label>{{$bt->student_name}}</label>
      @endforeach
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

**Script**

```
$('#chckHead').click(function() {
  if (this.checked == false) {
    $('.chcktbl:checked').attr('checked', false);
  } else {
    $('.chcktbl:not(:checked)').attr('checked', true);
  }
});
$('#chckHead').click(function () {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current table row with `$(this).parents('tr')` and use find to select the checkboxes in the current row.

```
$('#chckHead').click(function () {
    if (this.checked == false) {
        $(this).parents('tr').find('.chcktbl:checked').attr('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $(this).parents('tr').find('.chcktbl:not(:checked)').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

or just do:

```
$('#chckHead').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.chcktbl:checked').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selectAll').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.student').prop('checked', this.checked)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;vertical-align: top">
      <label>All A<input type="checkbox" class="selectAll"></label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">
      <label>Student A1<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label><br>
      <label>Student A2<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label><br>
      <label>Student A3<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;vertical-align: top">
      <label>All B<input type="checkbox" class="selectAll"></label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">
      <label>Student B1<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label><br>
      <label>Student B2<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label><br>
      <label>Student B3<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid;vertical-align: top">
      <label>All C<input type="checkbox" class="selectAll"></label></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid">
      <label>Student C1<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label><br>
      <label>Student C2<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label><br>
      <label>Student C3<input type="checkbox" class="student"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: it work but only in the first row how do i loop this command to all row

Comment: that is because you use an id, and you are not allowed to have the same id twice. change id `chckHead` to class. Never use static id's in loops.

Comment: Okay hold on ill change

Comment: changed to selector `$('#chckHead')` to `$('.chckHead')` too?

Comment: `.prop('checked', this.checked)` is the way you should use it instead of `.attr('checked', this.checked)`. The last one give me problems in my snippet when toggle it off and on multiple times. `prop()` seems to work great.

Comment: yeah its true .prop works fine, when u uncheck some checkbox then check again all it work, on the other side when i use the .attr it wont check the selected uncheck box u need to refresh the page before u can check all haha